# How to identify best Max_bucket and Seed_value for Oracle ORA_Hash function?

Tags: sql, oracle, hash

I am new to Oracle Hash function. I know that this function is for encryption purpose. It is actually convert a very large paragraph into one single hash value.

The Ora_hash function have three different parameters:

- Expression
- Max_bucket
- Seed_value

For the Max_bucket and seed value, the document says I can specify between 0  to 429496725. Max_bucket is default to 429496725 and Seed_Value is default to 0.

However, does anyone know what is the difference between 0 and 429496725 for those values?

I am actually planning to use it to compare two columns from two different tables, each rows in each columns have close to 3000 characters, and 1 table will have  close to 1 million of records while the other will have close to billions of records. Of course both table can be joined with an ID columns.

As a result of this, I think using a hash value will be a better option than simply using A = B.

However, could anyone teach me how to identify best Max_bucket and Seed_value for Oracle ORA_Hash function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there something in the documentation that is not clear?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for guiding me back to the document again. After reviewed the document again, I think I should use “0” for my seed value, but I am still not very understand about the max_bucket. Could you please share me some light?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ORA_HASH`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions136.htm#SQLRF06313) is not intended for generating unique hash values.  You probably want to use a function like [`STANDARD_HASH`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm#SQLRF55647) instead.

`ORA_HASH` is intended for situations where you want to quickly throw a bunch of values into a group of buckets, and hash collisions are useful.  `ORA_HASH` is useful for hash partitioning; for example, you might want to split a table into 64 segments to improve manageability.

`STANDARD_HASH` can be used to generate practically-unique hashes, using algorithms like MD5 or SHA.  These hash algorithms are useful for cryptographic purposes, whereas `ORA_HASH` would not be suitable.  For example:

```
select standard_hash('asdf') the_hash from dual;

THE_HASH
--------
3DA541559918A808C2402BBA5012F6C60B27661C
```

Comment: Hi Jon, 

Just can't resist myself to give you a big thank you! You have resolved a big problem for me. :) Thank you very much!